# How to filter a angular table tb if data is == 0

Tags: angularjs

I have 3 different companies a user can be assigned to. A 0 is being displayed in the user.CompanyName if it is Null. How can filter the 0 to not show?

```
 <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:search" ng-click="selectUser(user)" style="cursor:pointer">
   <td>{{user.CompanyName1 | slug}}<br /> {{user.CompanyName2 | slug}}<br /> {{user.CompanyName3 | slug}} </td>
   <td>{{user.Name}}</td>
   <td>{{user.UserName}}</td>
   <td>{{user.Email}}</td>
   </tr>
```

Slug Filter

```
 app.filter('slug', function () {
return function (input) {
    if (input) {
        return input.replace(/[_]/g, ' ');
    }
   };
 });
```

JSON

```
[  
   {  
      "$id":"1",
      "Id":"0d286ee5-7408-46dc-9519-1d58e42691d3",
      "Name":"Rudy Sanchez",
      "UserName":"admin",
      "Email":"texa@gmail.com",
      "CompanyName1":"Transparent Energy",
      "CompanyName2":null,
      "CompanyName3":null
   }
]
```

Comment: what is slug in your code?

Comment: null companyNames already will not be shown according to this "slug" filter, since these null values cannot pass the "if(input)" statement. Update your question with sample companyNames data that shows as 0.

Comment: cannot reproduce: http://plnkr.co/edit/HDUtFnYuxkeoFngk3Db1?p=preview.   maybe the problem is in your `filter:search`?